# PYPY translate exception

Tags: python, pypy

I'm trying to generate from a simple python named test.py script the c code,
the command that I'm using is:

```
python rpython  --source  ~/work/test.py.
```

I don't get what I'm doing  wrong because from the exception that I received in the output I don't  understand much :

`Exception: file '/work/test.py' is not a valid targetxxx.py`.

Any idea what should i do to avoid the exception?

Comment: This question is answered in the F.A.Q.: http://rpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-is-rpython .  (Anyone that feels like copying parts of the FAQ as a full answer is welcome to.)

Comment: not sure which part of FAQ you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue; what fixed it for me was adding the target function to my main script:

```
    def target(*args):
       return entry_point, None
```

hope it helps :)